# Последовательный вызов ajax-запросов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно последовательно длительное время делать `ajax`-запросы к одному и тому же скрипту на сервере. После окончания одного запроса тут же делать следующий и так до тех пор, пока сервер не выполнит задачу. Боюсь делать запросы в `callback`-функции `ajax`'а, как бы не возникло `stackoverflow`'а. Подскажите, кто знает, есть ли такая вероятность и если есть, то как правильно такое организовать? В таймере нельзя, потому что мы не знаем, сколько времени будет работать сервер над каждым запросом.

Comment: @meine, как раз про рекурсию и был вопрос - не возникнет ли переполнения стека.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Боюсь делать запросы в callback-функции ajax'а, как бы не возникло
> stackoverflow'а.

Надо быть смелым. Не бойтесь. Делайте. Для асинхронных ajax-запросов stack overflow не будет.

Comment: Если он будет, то какой смысл их делать? Нужно искать метод, который позволит делать запросы без переполнения стека.

Comment: @nup Пропустил "не".

Comment: оно и удивительно, если не будет. Вы не могли бы обосновать?

Comment: @nup Выполнение вернется обратно вверх по стеку вызовов от кода, отправляющего запрос, задолго до того, как вызовется асинхронный callback. В этом смысл асинхронности.

Comment: почему-то я вам верю, это кажется логичным. Спасибо, будем пробовать.

Comment: @nup Вы это можете проверить, выводя сообщения в консоль браузера до и после запроса, а также в callback-функции.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте рекурсивный вызов. Поставте ограничение на количество попыток, можно таймер.

Comment: Ограничение ставить нельзя, потому что работать должно до тех пор, пока сервер не выполнит задачу. Либо, ставить ограничение, потом запускать таймер и в таймере - новую рекурсию. Нет ли какого-то более простого способа это организовать?

Comment: Циклом while еще можно